# How to make <code> snippet to appear with line numbers, toggling and other features

Tags: jquery, html, css, wordpress

I wanted HTML's CODE tag appear as on this page. (ie with line numbers, alternate pattern and toggling between HTML and Text exactly on this page.)

http://www.webmonkey.com/2010/02/get_started_with_rest/

Let me know if you know any code snippet, Jquery plugin or wordpress plug in (I'm not looking for codepress but exactly as on this page).

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Judging by some of the JS/CSS files downloaded by that page, it looks like it's using [SyntaxHighlighter](http://alexgorbatchev.com/wiki/SyntaxHighlighter).

Comment: SyntaxHighlighter is a quite know, well, syntay highlighter. It a javascript plugin that you can install to almost any site. Take a look at Jason's link for info.